# Windows10 disk utility how to differ one disk from another?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, dualboot

I have 2 of the same SSDs (Samsung EVO 840 120GB)

- one is EXT4 (data drive for linux)
- one is NTFS (used for gaming on linux), which I formatted in linux using (`mkfs.ntfs -L Games`)

Windows wont mount the NTFS drive, so I tried to format it using windows disk utility. Problem is: it does not show detailed information. Both the EXT4 and the NTFS drive are looking exactly the same. "Right-Click > Properties > Details" wont display any information that would help me differ between drives either (like a serial number would be helpful)

How would I be able to know what drive I have to format?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself using a (imho too complicated) way:

1. using the software `DiskInternals Linux Reader` which was able to read the `-L GamesNTFS` label that I created with `mkfs.ntfs` under linux.
2. inside DiskInternals:

   1. right-click the correctly labeled disk
   2. select `Properties`
   3. switch to `Physical Disk` tab in `Properties` modal
   4. "Serial Number" displays the Disk number
      remember that disk number (`Disk 1` in my case)
3. inside windows disk utility

   1. right click on the remembered disks volume (`Disk 1` in my case)
   2. delete volumes
   3. create new volume
4. finally windows mounts the newly created volume.